# Dynamic Web fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

What I'm trying to do is I have a User profile page that I got with basic fields etc, But now I want to add 2 additional field types and I'm not doing to well with them.

Basically the fields are the same, I have a dynamic selection with list 2 depending on list 2 selection, but I need to be able to have a button for adding more of these fields, and likewise if user edits his profile it needs to be able to remove a specific one.

The 2nd is just a free text field but also needs to be able to add more and then remove specific. I'm not 100% sure how I'll store these in the database as well. I'm using MySQL for this all.

Comment: please share relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
Well I figured it out using a ajax method ^_^
sorry I didn't include the original code I had 50 things on my mind.

Basic code:
mysql Data pull:

```
$getCountries = "Select * from countries";
$CountriesResult = mysqli_query($con, $getCountries);
```

PHP Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Location">Location:</label>
    <select id="country" class="form-control" required name="country" onchange="getprov(this.value);" >
        <option value="">--Select country--</option>
            <?php
                while($country_dataRow = mysqli_fetch_array($CountriesResult)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country_dataRow['Country_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $country_dataRow['name']; ?></option>;
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
   </div>
<!-- Province -->
<div id="province-data" class="form-group"></div>
```

Then Java Scripting

```
function getprov(val){
$("#province-data").html("<img src='assets/images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type:   "POST",
        url:    "ajax_call.php",
        data:   "Country_ID="+val,
        success:    function(data){
                        $("#province-data").html(data);
                    }
        })
    }, 500);
};
```

lastly the Ajax_call.php

```
$getProvince = "Select * from province where Country_ID='$country_id' order by Province asc";
$ProvinceResult = mysqli_query($con, $getProvince);

<select id="province" class="form-control" required name="province" onchange="getcity(this.value);">
    <option value="">--Select Province--</option>
    <?php while($province_dataRow = mysqli_fetch_array($ProvinceResult)){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $province_dataRow['Province_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $province_dataRow['Province']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

I'm still working on the adding multiple entries on the system.